# Adding and handling custom html tag/div in TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE in one of my project where TinyMCE 4.0+ is used for some report designing. It also provides to insert some formulas to get solved on run time by report engine. These formulas can be complex and I want user to give some tool to manage these formulas like this...

1. A Custom Toolbar button, that will open a jQuery Dialog containing a form to get that formula designed and on submit puts that formal string at cursor location in a div with some specific class. (Can find this step on google, but still if any better solution)
2. [Actual Problem] But editing this formula should also be by that Dialog and form, so when user clicks that div (created in previous step with specific class) that jQuery Dialog should open and populate form with that values.

[image]

And If possible user should not be able to edit text in that div by manual means.

Since reports might be long a good and optimised coding standard is more welcome here.

Comment: What particular issue are you having? What code have you written and where is it failing?

Comment: Hey Michael, Adding toolbar and adding content on cursor location is okay, but I have no idea how to implement second requirement. since it requires getting cursor location, get parent tag with specified class and open dialog if it matches ... 

Right now, I am working around https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/ 

But any plugin like mention is more than welcome ...